# Illegal symbol DECLARE in DB2 z/OS Trigger

Tags: sql, variables, triggers, db2

I got the following statement:

```
-- @delimiter is for DBVizualizer!
@delimiter `;
--#SET TERMINATOR`
CREATE TRIGGER FOOSCHEMA.AFTER_UPDATE_FOOTABLE
AFTER UPDATE OF
        FOO,
        FEE,
        FAA,
        FII,
        FUU
ON FOOSCHEMA.FOOTABLE REFERENCING
        OLD AS "OLD_FOO" 
        NEW AS "NEW_FOO"
FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL
BEGIN ATOMIC
    DECLARE TEST VARCHAR(255);
END `
--#SET TERMINATOR ;
@delimiter ;`
```

which returns me the following error when I do execute it:

> [Code: -104, SQL State: 42601]  ILLEGAL SYMBOL "DECLARE". SOME SYMBOLS
> THAT MIGHT BE LEGAL ARE:. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.26.14

Why?

Comment: It seems DB2 z/OS has missing features. Someone mentioned that here https://stackoverflow.com/a/10011060/2739334

Comment: What version of Db2 for z/OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not assume that Db2-for-Z/OS has the same syntax as Db2 on other platforms (such as Db2-for-Linux/Unix/Windows/cloud, or Db2-for-i ).

The SQL flavour supported by Db2-for-Z/OS allow exploitation of the hardware/software features specific to the underlying hardware platform. Some of those features do not currently exist on other hardware platforms that run Db2-for-Linux/Unix/Windows/cloud. That's why the SQL syntax can differ, apart from historic reasons associated with the historically batch nature of processing on the mainframe platform.

For Db2-for-Z/OS, the syntax for a trigger body limits the SQL statements to a subset. The subset can differ with the Db2-for-Z/OS version.

For currently shopping Db2-for-Z/OS versions, you cannot use DECLARE in the trigger body. You must examine what you are trying to achieve and find a different supported method to give the same result, for example to use "CALL" to access SQL PL functionality.

For v11 of Db2-for-Z/OS you can see the allowed statements in a trigger-body [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_11.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sql_createtrigger.html).

You can also use that page to change to your version of the Db2-for-Z/OS product to see what SQL statements are allowed in the trigger body, and in particular examine the V12 advanced trigger capability.